# nginx + php-fpm/hhvm specific openbase_dir requirement

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, hhvm

I have structure like this:

```
  user1 - site - public - functions.php
  user1 - site - public - functions.php
  appuser - app - index.php
```

nginx sets php to appuser - app - index.php which includes app and then individual functions.php for users

users have ftp access to their public directories

how can i limit that user cannot include or modify anything below his public directory but the app/index.php can do anything